# Localized date not translating the days

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

Here is how I am localising days:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *dayFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dayFormat];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *day = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

And yet it seems to be returning English days of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc) rather than the device language (which has been set to German in the simulator).

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**Update** after doing some research on device I've realised that its actually the region setting, not the language setting which changes the date language. Odd, but I guess its done for a reason.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE"

Comment: do you have lproj for german?

Comment: I'm trying to get the localized version of the date. @"EEEE" is the format string for a full day e.g. "Monday" as opposed to "Mon" or "M".

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes I do, but I don't have any date strings in it, I assumed that it would be handled by NSDateFormatter automatically

Answer (score 1):

The language of the date is set by the *region* not the *language*. This has to be a bug. If I'm in Germany, but an English speaker I don't want to have my dates in German, surely?

Anyway, this is why. You have to change language and region.

Comment: I know it's a bit weird but it's by design. If you're in Germany but you're an English speaker, you probably wouldn't set your Region setting to German as you'd then get the German standards for things like number formats (1,0 instead of 1.0) and date and time formats. It just happens to be that long date formats require a word for the day and month, and these are in the language of the format (German, if you have German formats). A mix of languages and cultural formats would be weird and in theory could be impossible (a regional rule could depend on a language-specific grammar rule)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. It wouldn't work on the simulator, but it would on a device. Can you try it ? I did not however solve it, I did not even look more into it as it was working perfectly on the device, which is truly the main target of your app.

---

Edit:

This comes from [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ### currentLocale
>
> Returns the logical locale for the current user.
>
> `+ (id)currentLocale`
>
> Return Value
>
> The logical locale for the current user. The locale is formed from the settings for the current user’s chosen system locale overlaid with any custom settings the user has specified in System Preferences.
>
> Discussion
>
> Settings you get from this locale do not change as a user’s
>   Preferences are changed so that your operations are consistent.
>   Typically you perform some operations on the returned object and then
>   allow it to be disposed of. Moreover, since the returned object may be
>   cached, you do not need to hold on to it indefinitely. Contrast with
>   autoupdatingCurrentLocale.

Maybe you can try using:

> ### preferredLanguages
>
> Returns the user's language preference order as an array of strings.
>
> `+ (NSArray *)preferredLanguages`
>
> Return Value
>
> The user's language preference order as an array of NSString objects, each of which is a canonicalized IETF BCP 47 language identifier.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. However, instead of changing the *language* if you change the *region* it changes the date language. Odd... so I have the device set to British English (language) but Germany (region) and its giving me German dates. :/

Comment: @ThomasClayson: I edited my answer. Maybe you can try it, but **beware**, I'm not sure at all this is the good solution !

Comment: Hmm, that might be a good idea. :) I would expect that apple's way of working is the expected functionality however. We'll soon find out! :)